# D3 Accessing node attributes inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, svg

I'm new to D3 and I'm trying to set the attributes for some bars inside a bar chart. I select all the rects with `d3.selectAll("rect")` and store them in an array (an array of arrays actually). Then I slice the sub-array to store only the rects and when I try to set their attributes I get an `.attr is not a function` error. I guess it is related to the array items not being svg nodes but I don't know how to solve it.

Here is the code:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d, index) {
  var allBars = d3.select("#chart").selectAll("rect");
  var leftBars = [];
  var rightBars = [];

  leftBars = allBars[0].slice(0, index);
  rightBars = allBars[0].slice(index+1);

  for (i = 0; i < leftBars.length; i++) {
    leftBars[i].attr("transform", "translate(-20, 0)");
  }

  for (i = 0; i < rightBars.length; i++) {
    rightBars[i].attr("transform", "translate(20, 0)");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just figured it out.

It's as simple as transforming the array into a D3 selection.

```
.on("mouseover", function(d, index) {
  var allBars = d3.select("#chart").selectAll("rect");
  var leftBars = [];
  var rightBars = [];

  leftBars = allBars[0].slice(0, index);
  rightBars = allBars[0].slice(index+1);

  d3.selectAll(leftBars)
    .attr("transform", "translate(-20, 0)");
  d3.selectAll(rightBars)
    .attr("transform", "translate(20, 0)");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A more compact way would be...

```
.on("mouseover", function(d, index) {
  d3.select("#chart").selectAll("rect")
    .attr("transform", function(d,i){
        return i = index ? null : "translate(" + (i < index ? -20: 20) + ", 0)";
    }
});
```